# Spring boot issue main class gives compilation error

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors

While running main class `SpringBoot2RestServiceApplication` i got the following exception:

```
cannot access org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

It shows compilation error:

[image: compilation error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove(delete) your local repo (~/.m2/repository/) and run `mvn clean install` again.